# boost.asio + native windows sockets

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio, winsock2

We have a framework that communicates via native WinAPI sockets (`WSASend` , CompletionPorts, etc) via **TCP**.

Recently, we've added some classes to this framework that also async sends and receives some messages via **UDP**, but these classes use `Boost.ASIO` (`io_context` etc).

Since then, we noticed that WinSocks `connect` function fails, with the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond. The thread 0x3038
> has exited with code 0 (0x0)

- This only fails when connecting to a remote computer, not locally.
- When reverting to an older version without these Boost classes, everything works fine (ruling out firewall issues)
- When the Boost.ASIO classes our used outside of the framework, they work fine.

We are unsure what causes this issue. My hunch is that it is a conflict on OS level between winsock and boost.ASIO.

Did anyone run into something similar? Any ideas or pointers would be really appreciated.

Ben